# Flexdashboard disable shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, shinyjs

I have a sidebar with multiple shiny `selectInput` (country and year). This sidebar is the same for all pages (Summary and World Map) of my flexdashboard. How can I disable the country input on the Summary page ?

I've tried using `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` but I don't know how to use it in a flexdashboard framework.

````
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: yeti
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyjs::useShinyjs()
``` //


Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
selectInput("countryInput", "Select a country", choices = sort(c(data_long$cname)), selected = 1)

selectInput("yearInput", "Select a year", choices = c(data_long$year), selected = 10)

shinyjs::disable("countryInput")
``` //


Summary
=====================================

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Graph 1

```{r}

omitted

``` //



### Graph 2

```{r}

omitted

``` //


Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Data

```{r}

omitted

``` //


World map
=====================================


Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### map


```{r}

omitted

``` //
````

EDIT: spelling

Comment: Does [this](https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/advanced#usage-dashboard) help?

Comment: Almost. Flexdashboard has a different structure that does not involve any ui and server functions, that's why all other questions I've seen on stackoverflow cannot help me. See here for flexdashboard: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html